# Looking for an animated Children's TV show about time travel

Tags: story-identification

I am certain that this aired on CITV, and it was an animated cartoon children's TV show which probably aired in between the years 2006-09, possibly later. I can remember that it was a trio of kids, three boys I think, (although sometimes there was a girl with them too) who could time travel somehow. I can vaguely remember details such as them accidentally changing time so Napoleon invaded England and everyone ended up speaking French, which they then went back and fixed.

As far as I can remember, the animation style was quite simplistic, but I think it was computer animated in the style of hand-drawn animation.

Comment: Do you mean CITV?

Comment: @jim Wow, I really do lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was it a cartoon called [Time Warp Trio](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0813910/episodes?season=-1&ref_=ttep_ep_sn_nx)?

Comment: Do the plot elements match?

Comment: Thank you so much, a quick google search and it all matches up! :D